# Is paypal-community legitimate, or is it phishing?

Tags: paypal, phishing

I see this website
https://www.paypal-community.com

I worry that if I was to mistype a letter it could go to a phishing site

I also worry that the site itself isn't legitimate.

Is it, and what can I do about worrying that if I mistype a letter or do org instead of com, that it might go to a wromg one?

Answer (score 3):

You actually can't do anything. Just be careful. There are a lot of famous websites all over the internet and a lot more of phishing clones with slightly different domain-name.

Maybe I'm wrong but bookmarking correct address seems like safer solution to me. At least, you can't type wrong letter or top-domain.

Answer (score 1):

When you log into paypal and paypal-commynity, do you see the exact same address in the address bar, if yes, then it's legitimate, or else it's a scam.

Let me explain it to you with an example: Google, no matter whether you log into gmail, orkut, picasa, docs, drive..while entering the userid and password, the address is always and always accounts.google.com/.....

Answer (score 0):

It is owned by PayPal

(as seen from clicking the padlock icon - the padlock icon was introduced into chrome in 2011). After clicking the padlock icon, click on "connection is secure"(which I think just means it's an https site, which doesn't mean it's not dodgy), but clicking that then it says that the SSL certificate was issued to PayPal, which means it's legitimate.

[image]